# Correct Date format on import - Getting errors when importing csv file

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-import

I am getting constant errors when importing a csv file into marketing cloud. It seems that no matter which date format I choose, the file still errors although most of the records go in, but not all. This is what MC notification says:

Results:

```
Inserted: 174838
```

ValidationErrors:

```
Invalid Date: 1825
```

This is the date format in the csv file:

2019-01-31

Example Records (I have removed sensitive info):
This one failed:
"3245123","251205123","xxxxxxxxxxxxx","2014","XXXX","Extended","Active","","MCCSO","12345678","me@me.com","My Company Co.","Suite 123","","","XXXXX","VI","00801","","","","","UP888","VIISI","2019-01-31","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

This one was inserted:
"71443123","20295433","XXXXXXXXXXX","2019","XXXXX","iiwjjwiiiiiw","Active","ME","ME","7268164","","My Services SERVICES INC.","162025 Main Road somewhere","","","SomeCity","GA","9399200","Somewhere else","LALA Land","LA","123232","BT56776","US","2020-02-29","","","","","","","","","","","","","Y","Status","2022-01-11",""

Can anyone recommend a format which should work with this?

Thanks

Comment: Since you have managed to insert 174838, then I suspect the date format being inconsistent in your file. Or is the date field only populated on 1825 records?

Comment: Hi Lukas, the date format is consistent across all records and in the same format. Its strange that MC will import some but not all records

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_supported_date_time_format.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes I have been there. Going by that doc Afrikaans (South Africa) would be a good fit. I have already tried that and get the same error.

Comment: fr_CA is normally my preferred date format for yyyy-mm-dd, with 24h time format. You might want to give it a try

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Still erroring though for some reason (on the same records)

Comment: Can you share more details on the records which are passing vs failing (by updating your question)? You can find the details in the file attached to the Data Extension Import Notification. I am especially curious to see if timestamps on failed records have anything in common.

Comment: I have updated the question. Appreciate the help.

Comment: from your file examples, you have two date fields in the working one. the errored one contains only one. so the error could be in a missing date (with empty string triggering a row to be deemed invalid), which would fit to the seemingly random number of invalids. We assume when all dates have the same format that either all or none fail. so that might be worth isolating.